# A circular definition of LONG_MAX in limits.h

Tags: c

The following definition in limits.h header of GNU C compiler,

```
#define LONG_MAX    2147483647L
```

The L suffix used indicates the number 2147483647 should be treated as a long integer literal. But the statement is actually the definition of long integer, so doesn't using L as suffix make the definition circular and therefore illogical?.

I am believing that LONG_MAX is playing a role in the definition of long int by specifying the maximum range of it. In short long int refers to LONG_MAX, the L in LONG_MAX refers to long int.

Comment: How do you get a definition of long int from the name `LONG_MAX`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler knows what a `long int` is because it is built into the compiler, not because of what is in `limits.h`.

`limits.h` provides information to programs using the compiler, not to the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a definition of a type, this is a literal constant.

Answer (score 4):

`#define` is used by the preprocessor for basic text replacement so the string `2147483647L` just replaces the string `LONG_MAX` before any compilation-work of `long` or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The line you quote does not define what a `long int` is. It defines the value of the `LONG_MAX` macro as a constant with value 2147483647 and specifies it is of `long int` type.

After the text substitution performed by the preprocessor, this will replace any instances of `LONG_MAX`.